# Location altitude always 0.0 for my service(fusedLocation)

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I need to know if there is a way to get the location with fusedLocation Api, actually i am implementing a service this service has a method that returns the location, the location is refreshing each time on the service so i get it on my desired activity.

With lat and lon everything is correct, except for altitude, i always get 0.0 is there a way using fusedlocation to get the altitude?

**here is my service code:**

```
package com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.services;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class GoogleLocation extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 0;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 0;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 0f;
    private int updatePriority;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private Intent intent;
    private String provider;
    Context context;


    Location mLastLocation;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public GoogleLocation getServerInstance() {
            return GoogleLocation.this;
        }
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        Log.d("IMHERE", "HELLO");
        return mLastLocation;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        context = getApplicationContext();
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();

        if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            this.updatePriority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
        } else if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            this.updatePriority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY;
        } else {
            this.updatePriority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
        }

        this.buildGoogleApiClient();
        this.createLocationRequest();
        this.googleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(this.googleApiClient, this.locationRequest,this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        Log.d("localizacao",mLastLocation.toString());
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();

        this.googleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
        this.googleApiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(this);
        this.googleApiClient.disconnect();
        this.mLastLocation = null;
    }



    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        this.googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        this.locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        this.locationRequest.setInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        this.locationRequest.setPriority(updatePriority);

    }
```

thank you!

Comment: Are you testing on a real device? And does location.hasAltitude() return true?

Comment: hasAltitude returns me false, but why it returns me false everywhere ?:S

Comment: Try testing on several real devices if you have them, in order to exclude any hardware/implementation issues. Also, try forcing PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY for now.